# Colocar imagen cargada en un input file como background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

Buenas tardes comunidad!

Necesito saber si existe la forma de utilizar una imagen cargada en un input file para previsualizarlo pero no en una etiqueta img, sino para poner la imagen como background-image de un div.

Antiguamente en el proyecto si cargaba la previsualización en un img de la siguiente forma

El input file

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="file_url" type="file" name="foto">
</div>      

            <div class="card-carga hide" id="contenedor_noticia2">
                <div class="card__father">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card__front" id="fondo-card">
                            <div class="bg"></div>
                            <div class="body__card__front">
                                <h2 id="titulo_noticia2"></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__back">
                            <div class="body__card__back">
                                <p id="texto_noticia2"></p>
                                <a id="link_noticia2" href="#!" target="blank_" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Leer m&aacute;s</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

function mostrarImagen(input) {;
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#img_destino2').attr('src', e.target.result);
                
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    
    $("#file_url").change(function(){
        $('#contenedor_noticia').removeClass("hide");
        $('#contenedor_noticia').addClass("show");
        $('#contenedor_noticia2').removeClass("hide");
        $('#contenedor_noticia2').addClass("show");
        mostrarImagen(this);
    });
```

Se me ocurrió con las siguientes opciones

```
$('#fondo-card').css("background-image", "url(e.target.result)"); 
$('#fondo-card').css("background-image", "url('e.target.result')"); 

var div= document.getElementById("div");
imagen.style.backgroundImage = "url('e.target.result')";
```

Saludos!
Gustavo Duarte

Comment: Sí, seguramente existe. ¿que has investigado al respecto?  ¿que has intentado?  Por favor, léete [ask] donde lo primero que dicen es "Busca e investiga", y no parece que lo hayas hecho.  De paso léete [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento correcto del sitio, gracias!

Comment: Actualice la pregunta, gracias!

Comment: Muy bien, gracias. Pon tambien el input file y el div, es decir, el HTML que se necesita para poder reproducir tu escenario, gracias.

Comment: Ya puse el html, gracias

Comment: Bien, ejem... ¿y donde está **img_destino2**?  entiendo que es el div destino o una imagen contenida en el más bien

Comment: O sea, me interesa saber que id tiene el div al cual le quieres poner ese background... ¿es alguno de los que muestras?

Comment: img_destino2 ya no se utilizara mas, en donde quiero poner la imagen como background-image es para el div con id "fondo_card"

Comment: Gracias por la paciencia en completar la pregunta como debía ser. Ya te he dado una respuesta que puedes ejecutar aquí mismo para ver su funcionamiento. Espero te ayude.

Comment: Gracias a ti por ayudarme ! te lo agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
const [archivo_imagen] = file_url.files
if (archivo_imagen) {
    $("#fondo-card").css("background-image", "url(" + URL.createObjectURL(archivo_imagen) + ")");
}
```

donde asignamos a la constante **archivo_imagen** un objeto del tipo [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) al archivo que se pretende subir mediante [files](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications), y luego, mediante [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) sacamos su ruta temporal para agregarla al css **background-image** usando el método [css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) de jquery

Ejemplo:

```js
$("#file_url").change(function() {
//  $('#contenedor_noticia').removeClass("hide");
//  $('#contenedor_noticia').addClass("show");
  $('#contenedor_noticia2').removeClass("hide");
  $('#contenedor_noticia2').addClass("show");

  const [archivo_imagen] = file_url.files
  if (archivo_imagen) {
    $("#fondo-card").css("background-image", "url(" + URL.createObjectURL(archivo_imagen) + ")");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input id="file_url" type="file" name="foto">
</div>

<div class="card-carga hide" id="contenedor_noticia2">
  <div class="card__father">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__front" id="fondo-card" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <div class="body__card__front">
          <h2 id="titulo_noticia2"></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <div class="body__card__back">
          <p id="texto_noticia2"></p>
          <a id="link_noticia2" href="#!" target="blank_" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Leer m&aacute;s</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda ! masterguru ;)

Comment: Un placer ayudar cuando la colaboración es mútua :-)  Lamento haberte hecho sudar pidiéndote los datos, pero para dar una buena respuesta la pregunta debe ser también completa. Saludos!